# Series Solutions Near an Ordinary Point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am attempting to solve this problem for practice: $y"-(x-3)y' - y = 0$ at $x_{0} = 3$.

But it appears as though I don't have an idea of the best approach to employ to go about solving it.

Can someone help me understand the steps in solving a DE such as this?  I know that a power series is required, but the garden variety method of solution doesn't appear to be working for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What series do you look for?  $y = c_0+c_1(x-3)+c_2(x-3)^2+\dots$.  Then what do you do with it?

Comment: You could do power series...or you could try transforming it into a first order ode. Hint: $$-(x-3)y'-y=\frac{d}{dx}((3-x)y)$$ Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: @GEdgar - Well, what I did is expressed y, y' and y" in terms of their derivative power series, and tried to go about it that way.  Here's the start of my work, up until where I felt my method was incorrect: http://imgur.com/QzNqY9R

Comment: @TylerHG - I need to solve it using the power series method.

Comment: @GEdgar - Does the work I showed take me in the right direction anywhere?

Comment: Yes you are going in the right direction. You really need to try to get each sum to have coefficients of $x^n$ then try to pull out terms to move everything into one sum.

Comment: @GEdgar - That is where I became confused.  I just don't know how to continue with the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It looks much simpler than that. Try differentiating $\exp(-3x+\frac{1}{2}x^2)$.

This seems to be attracting down votes. So maybe I should add a little more. If you do that you find that it is a solution to $y''-(x-3)y'-y=0$. Note also that the equation is linear, so you can take any constant multiple and the solution still works. Of course, there is another solution which is harder to find. But you have not specified the initial conditions clearly, so you may not need it.